# android open link in external `WebView` and loads it at internal webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with android `WebView` in my app. I have a fragment which contains a `WebView` (called 'A'); and I can detect when user click on a link inside A, and I open this link in an external `WebView` (called 'B'). But, when I go back to my link, 'A' has loaded the link too; and I need that 'A' remains in the webpage the user was reading when he/she clicked on the link.
I'm overriding the following methods:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return false;
        }

 @Override
 public void onLoadResource(WebView webView, String url) {
        //launch the url in an outer webview
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

  }
});
```

I tried should Override UrlLoading returning `true` and `false` , and no matter what value is returning, my app is always loading the url inside the 'A' webview; and I need that the link only load at 'B' webview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method only. See below.

```
boolean isLoadingFirstTime = true;
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (isLoadingFirstTime) {
                        isLoadingFirstTime = false;
                        view.loadUrl(url); // When you load your url
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))); // When user clicks on any link
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading is deprecated.